# How to copy a table from one database to another database in same ADX Cluster

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I want to copy table from One database to another database in same ADX (Azure Data Explorer) cluster.

From Microsoft document I could see table copy available within same database using below commands.

.set, .append, .set-or-append, .set-or-replace

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/data-ingestion/ingest-from-query

I am looking for a table copy from one database to another database in same ADX Cluster. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `database()` function for example:

```
.set Table <| database("myOtherDatabase").Table
```

Comment: thank you so much @Avnera, It is perfectly working.